# Conditional switch statements in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm quite used to vb.net's [`Select Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) syntax which is essentially a switch statement, where you can do things like `Case Is > 5` and if it matches, it will execute that case.

How can I do what I'm going to call "conditional switch statements" since I don't know the actual name, in PHP?

Or, what's a quick way to manage this?

```
switch($test)
{
    case < 0.1:
        // do stuff
        break;
}
```

That's what I've tried currently.

Comment: You'll have to use `if-elseif-else`. PHP doesn't support this syntax.

Comment: Only scalar values allowed for cases.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think you're searching for something like this (this is not exactly what you want or at least what I understand is your need).

`switch (true)` finds the cases which evaluate to a truthy value, and execute the code within until the first break; it encounters.

```
<?php

switch (true) {

case ($totaltime <= 1):
echo "That was fast!";
break;

case ($totaltime <= 5):
echo "Not fast!";
break;

case ($totaltime <= 10):
echo "That's slooooow";
break;
}

?>
```

Comment: @BoltClock: What does the true do?

Comment: And can I use floats here in the boolean expressions safely?

Comment: @Cyclone Yes, you can use float too.

Comment: @Cyclone super old but `true` in the switch tells the switch to always run. Its like a `while (true) {...}`

Comment: It's not different from a regular switch statement really. `true` is just a value, just like a variable holds a value. A switch just checks the cases to find the first one that has that same specified value.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to add this as a comment to the answer by BoltCock, but SO is telling me that his answer is locked so I'll make this a separate (and essentially redundant) answer:

The "switch(true)" answer from BoltCock is much like [the following example](http://web.archive.org/web/20120606012546/http://programmersnotes.info/2009/03/06/trick-with-php-switch/), which although logically equivalent to if + else if + else is arguably more beautiful because the conditional expressions are vertically aligned, and is standard/accepted practice in PHP.

But the if + else if + else syntax is essentially universal across scripting languages and therefore immediately readable (and maintainable) by anyone, which gives it my nod as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional way you can accomplish this, in PHP 8.0+, by using a [match statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php).

If you have a single expression within each case, it is equivalent to the following match statement. Note that unlike switch statements, we can choose to return a variable (in this code I am storing the result in `$result`).

```
$test = 0.05;
$result = match (true) {
    $test < 0.1 => "I'm less than 0.1",
    $test < 0.01 => "I'm less than 0.01",
    default => "default",
};

var_dump($result);
```

Match statements only allow you to have a single expression after each condition. You can work around this limitation by calling a function.

```
function tinyCase(){}
function veryTinyCase(){}
function defaultCase(){}

$test = 0.01;
match (true) {
    $test < 0.1 => tinyCase(),
    $test < 0.01 => veryTinyCase(),
    default => defaultCase(),
};
```

And for reference, if you just want to check for equality you can do:

```
$result = match ($test) { // This example shows doing something other than match(true)
    0.1 => "I'm equal to 0.1",
    0.01 => "I'm equal to 0.01",
    default => "default",
};
```

Match statements do have some key differences from switch statements that you need to watch out for:

- My last example will use a strict equality check `===` instead of a loose one `==`.
- If a default case is not provided, an UnhandledMatchError error is thrown when nothing matches.
- And there is no worrying about falling through to the next case if you forget to add `break`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports [switch statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). Is that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I know normal switch seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statement with conditions

```
switch(true)
{
    case ($car == "Audi" || $car == "Mercedes"):
        echo "German cars are amazing";
        break;
    case ($car == "Jaguar"):
        echo "Jaguar is the best";
        break;
    default:
        echo "$car is Ok";
}
```