# PHP fugly bug on case switch statement - PHP version 7.0.13

Tags: php

Everything works fine if $value is greater than 0 but if $value is set to 0 then case switch prints Billion :-).

Since the manual does not state that value 0 is not evaluated then this is a fugly bug to me. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
$value = 0;

    switch ($value) {
    case $value >= 1000000000:
      print 'Billion'; 
      break;
    case $value >= 1000000:
      print 'Million';
      break;
    case $value >= 1000 :
      print 'Thousand';
      break;
    default:
          print 'Ten';
      break;            
    }
```

.

```
Output: Billion  :-)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$value = 0;

    switch (true) {
    case ($value >= 1000000000):
      print 'Billion'; 
      break;
    case ($value >= 1000000):
      print 'Million';
      break;
    case ($value >= 1000) :
      print 'Thousand';
      break;
    default:
          print 'Ten';
      break;            
    }
```

please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7801218/6186468

Comment: This will work, but you should actually mark this question as a duplicate instead of repeating the answer.

Comment: I'll call this as a workaround.

Comment: It works so I marked it as accepted answer. But PHP case switch implementation is counter intuitive if not flat out illogical.

Comment: Yes I know this is not the way to code, but I just share how to solve it using switch case

Answer (score 4):

It is because switch case does not take expressions that can be evaluated. You should use `if else` for this. Eg of switch case:

```
$value = 2;
switch($value) {
    case 2:
        print "two";
    break;
    default:
        print "default";
}
```

Eg of `if else`:

```
$value = 3;
if( $value > 2 ) {
    print "greater than 2";
} elseif($value > 1) {
    print "greater than 1";
} else {
    print "default";
}
```

Comment: I love how a lot of developers goes straight to "it's a language bug" when they haven't read the manual properly and are using the language features wrong :-)

Comment: You were just 4 min faster. +1 for pointing out.

Comment: If $value is set to 1 then it works so obviously it does take an expression and evaluates it just fine.

Comment: Five upvotes for what? You asked your friends to upvote?

Comment: @Jimski `switch case` is not designed for this purpose. You can however use the suggested workaround.

Comment: @u_mulder actually, there were 7 up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` statements perform equality tests on the values in the cases. PHP is evaluating your comparisons, so `$value = 0` becomes case `false`. false is considered to be `equal to 0`, so the first case matches.

```
$value = 0;

switch (true) {
case ($value >= 1000000000):
  print 'Billion'; 
  break;
case ($value >= 1000000):
  print 'Million';
  break;
case ($value >= 1000) :
  print 'Thousand';
  break;
default:
      print 'Ten';
  break;            
}
```