# Converting a nested if-else based on range condition into switch statement

Tags: php

How can I convert following long if-else condition into switch case in PHP? Or, please suggest any feasible solution besides switch case.

```php
if($total_products >= 1 && $total_products <=10 ){

} elseif ($total_products >= 11 && $total_products <=25 ){

} elseif ($total_products >= 26 && $total_products <=40 ){

} elseif ($total_products >= 181 && $total_products <=200 ){

} elseif ($total_products >= 351 && $total_products <=400 ){

} elseif ($total_products >= 401 && $total_products <=500 ){

} elseif ($total_products > 500 ){

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional switch statements in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801175/conditional-switch-statements-in-php)

Comment: polymorphism seems to be a good idea to do it. You can check this link
https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: Why? What's wrong with this?

Comment: The switch statement in the proposed duplicate doesn't really improve much from your current code. And your current code could be simplified a bit if you remember that the code runs from top to bottom, which means you could have `if ($total_products <= 10) { ... } elseif ($total_products <= 25) { ... } ... etc...` That is, you don't need to specify a range in each condition, the ranges will be implicit due to the ordering of the `elseif`.

Comment: what should happen when 40 < $total_products < 181 ? @Jeto your example can't handle this case

Answer (score 2):

You can make a small function to do the job and can use it like this:

```
pubic function isInRange($value, $min, $max){
return ($value <= $max && $value >= $min);
}
```

you can use this function like this:

```
$value = 16;

$ranges = array(
  'range1'=> array(
    'min'=> 1,
    'max'=> 10
  ),
  'range2'=> array(
    'min'=> 11,
    'max'=> 20
  )
);

  function isInRange($value, $min, $max){
  return ($value <= $max && $value >= $min);
}

foreach($ranges as $key => $range){
  echo (isInRange($value, $range['min'], $range['max']))? $key.' returned true': $key.' returned false';
}
```

Comment: Could just `return $value <= $max && $value >= $min;` in that function.

Comment: @Jeto Done, I was thinking of that :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option is to use the [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) method:

```
filter_var(
$yourInteger, 
FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => $min, 
        'max_range' => $max
    )
)
```

);

Please, note that the filter_var method is type safe.
You will see many good working examples at the bottom of the php.net site i linked above.