# Switch Case Condition for Empty String

Tags: php

[image]

I can't explain this

```
public static function getIconBaseOnOS($os)
{

    switch ($os) {


        case (strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false):
        $icon = 'windows';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'WOW64') !== false):
        $icon = 'windows';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'iPhone') !== false):
        $icon = 'iphone';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'Mac') !== false):
        $icon = 'mac';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'Linux') !== false):
        $icon = 'linux';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'Android') !== false):
        $icon = 'android';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'Crawler') !== false):
        $icon = 'crawler';
        break;

        case (strpos($os, 'compatible') !== false):
        $icon = 'compatible';
        break;


        case (strpos($os, 'bot') !== false):
        $icon = 'bot';
        break;


        case '':
        $icon = 'na';
        break;

        case strlen($os) == 0:
        $icon = 'na';
        break;

        default:
        $icon = 'na';


    }

    return $icon;

}
```

## First 2 rows

My OS clearly == empty && length == 0.

I'm not sure why this case is not trigger `$icon = 'na';`, but instead it kept showing `windows` icon !! ‍♂️ How ?

Comment: `switch ($os) case (strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false) ` is equivalent to `if ($os == (strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false))`. Using a switch here makes no sense.

Comment: I don't get you.  Is my condition is wrong?

Comment: I followed the PHP document to check for string contain.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: The problem is not the usage of `strpos`, the problem is the wrong usage of a switch case

Comment: @deceze Why should I `if-else` when I have about 15 cases, and more ? I'm sticking with switch case any days.

Comment: @Cid Care to enlighten me ? I'm hoping to learn the right way of using the switch in PHP from you. ;)

Comment: I'm typing an answer, let's hope it will help

Comment: I'm following this answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7801218/4480164

Comment: that's different, you're comparing `$os` with the result of `(strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false)`

Comment: `switch` is a shortcut if the compared values are constant values. `switch ($foo) case 'bar':`. You don’t have that. You have `if..else` conditions.

Comment: The issues is much simpler than that guys... I added in the answer. There is no issue with my conditions.

Comment: @deceze There is a way to do conditions in switch cases, cleaner codes ;)

Comment: What’s cleaner about requiring an additional `break` for every case, since you’re not even interested in `switch`'s fall through behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how switch cases work.

As stated Deceze in comments, *" `switch ($os) case (strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false)`  is equivalent to `if ($os == (strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false))`"*

In example, if the input is `'iPhone'`, in the switch/case the first non false condition will be this one : `case (strpos($os, 'iPhone') !== false):`

Executing it step by step, you get :

```
strpos('iPhone', 'iPhone'); //0

0 !== false // true

'iPhone' == true // true ('iPhone', or any non empty string is a non falsy value, hence the condition being true)
```

Now, suppose you pass an empty string.

```
strpos('', 'Win64'); // false

false !== false // false

'' == false // true ! an empty string is considered as a falsy value.
```

I would advise to get rid of the switch case and use an array instead, like

```
function getIconBaseOnOS($os)
{
    $osArray = [
        'Win64'      => 'windows',
        'WOW64'      => 'windows',
        'iPhone'     => 'iphone',
        'Mac'        => 'mac',
        'Linux'      => 'linux',
        'Android'    => 'android',
        'Crawler'    => 'crawler',
        'compatible' => 'compatible',
        'bot'        => 'bot'
    ];

    foreach ($osArray as $osName => $iconName )
    {
        if (strpos($os, $osName) !== false)
        {
            return $iconName;
        }
    }
    
    return 'na';
}
```

Comment: The idea with the array is very good. Better yet, pass the $osArray as a parameter to the function.  +1 from me.

Comment: Thank-you Cid, I like your idea a lot. Adjusted my code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found my owned mistake

Instead of

`switch ($os) {`

I should do

`switch (true) {`

It's working perfectly now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be an optimized way to do this as you preferred however there are too many better ways to do the same thing.

```
// if empty string return whatever you want
if (strlen($os) <=0) 
    return  'na';

//when string is not empty 
switch ($os) {
    //when you need to run OR condition
    case (strpos($os, 'WOW64') !== false):
    case (strpos($os, 'Win64') !== false):
        $icon = 'windows';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'iPhone') !== false):
        $icon = 'iphone';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'Mac') !== false):
        $icon = 'mac';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'Linux') !== false):
        $icon = 'linux';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'Android') !== false):
        $icon = 'android';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'Crawler') !== false):
        $icon = 'crawler';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'compatible') !== false):
        $icon = 'compatible';
        break;
    case (strpos($os, 'bot') !== false):
        $icon = 'bot';
        break;
    default:
        $icon = 'na';
}
return $icon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement only compares the value of the variable you pass it.

```
$var = null;

switch($var)
{
    case null:
       echo '$var is NULL';
    break;

    case '':
       echo '$var has no value or is emtpy';
    break;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to do a condition in the switch case ?